# How to hide trailing .00's in decimal column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed a column from integer to decimal.

I will have values like:

```
10.5
100.5
100
300
300.5
```

When it's `100` or `300` it displays like `100.0` and `300.0` I'd like to remove the .0 part if it's a flat number.

How can I do this?

This seems to work: `value: "%g" % weight` from an input field. Doesn't seem pretty but it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can use .round(0)

e.g.

```
1.9.3-head :004 > foo = 100.2
=> 100.2
1.9.3-head :005 > foo.round(0)
=> 100
```